# How do I align tables with HTML?

Tags: html, css

First of all, I'm new to this stuff (like, just-started-two-days-ago new).  I've figured out how to generate tables from an XML file in my XSL file.  What I'm trying to do now is get them to align properly.  Now, I've used the align attribute of < table > to do this, and it works exactly the way I want it to, but I read that the align attribute was deprecated in HTML 4.01.  I read that you should use CSS for this when you're working with HTML.

I am currently under the impression that you should use XSLT instead of CSS when working with XML files.  So if I'm not supposed to use the align attribute on the grounds that it should be done in CSS, but I'm not supposed to use CSS with XML, what am I supposed to do?

**Is it still a good practice to use the align attribute of < table > in XSLT?**

I'm trying to write a Java program that uses XML to serialize files.  I'm aware that Java has a built in Serializable interface, but I want to do it this way anyways.  Originally, I was creating my own syntax to do this, but after some research, I realized that I was simply reinventing XML.  This XSLT project is kind of a diversion, but I think it might be a handy thing to have because it can display the XML files in a more readable way.

I have very little HTML experience, and basically no CSS experience.  I've never had a use for any of the stuff until now.  I've also never posted a question to this site before.

Comment: The question of alignment has nothing to do with XML or XSL. The only factor tht applies here is what you generate in the HTML (the content) so this is purely an HTML/CSS question.  If you were writing the HTML yourself, would you say the question was about "Typing"?

Comment: As the question seems to be about using a presentational attribute in HTML vs. styling in CSS, it is primarily an opinion-based question.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - Question whether to use `align` vs CSS isn't opinion based IMO - [HTML5 Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-html5-20121217/) clearly states that `align` on `<table>` is obsolete: `the following attributes are obsolete (though the elements are still part of the language), and must not be used by authors`. Even more, 1999 [HTML 4.01 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224) also marks it as deprecated.

Comment: A question is opinion-based if it really just asks for opinions and there are no solid technical grounds for resolving it. Opinions expressed in drafts (and specifications) are still just opinions. But if you think that a draft (which itself says that it is in appropriate to cite it except as work in progress) or a specification resolves the issue, then the question becomes trivial. As soon as you have formed your *opinion* about the draft or spec to swear by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:** Yes, it's a bad practice to use tables `align` attribute. You should use CSS instead.

I would:

- Use XSLT to transform XML into HTML
- Use CSS to style HTML document.

To do this, include in your XSLT sheet something like:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
 // ...
```

And then, put CSS into `style.css` to align tables.

To control table align, you could use this CSS, on example:

```
table {
  float: right;
}
```

---

Here is an example with inline CSS stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <style type="text/javascript">
          <xsl:text>
            table {
              float: right;
            }
          </xsl:text>
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <table>
          <xsl:for-each select="/records/record">
            <tr>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="age"/></td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It could be applied to this example document:

```
<records>
  <record>
    <name>Lorem</name>
    <age>32</age>
  </record>
  <record>
    <name>Ipsum</name>
    <age>65</age>
  </record>
</records>
```

Comment: Okay, and then using id and class selectors, you can specify which tables you want to apply it to.